# angular 2 IE9 getting 404's when loading script files

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-9

When I load `https://me.com:80/p/manage;Id=1234`

in ie10: `https://me.com:80/styles.bundle.js`
ie ie9: `https://me.com:80/p/styles.bundle.js`

in my index.html I have `<base href="/" />`

the scripts are added to index.html on build autogeneration:

```
<script src="styles.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is happening with all auto added scripts that angular2 relies on.

Why is the url in ie9 generated like this, is this fixable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to IE-9 and lower not supporting relative paths in the `<base href="">`

I've added a small script in my `<head>` to deal with this inconvenience.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var isLocal = true;
        var base, host;
        base = isLocal ? "/" : "/prod/ux/";
        if (!window.location.origin) {
            window.location.origin = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port: '');
        }
        host = window.location.origin + "";
        if(isLocal){/* needs to be changed for ie-9 testing */
          document.write("<base href='" + base + "' />");
          //document.write("<base href='https://" + window.location.host + base + "' />");
        }else{
          document.write("<base href='https://" + window.location.host + base + "' />");
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

add to your index.html:

```
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/angular/66df335998d097fa8fe46dec41f1183737332021/shims_for_IE.js" type="text/plain"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.9/es5-sham.js" type="text/plain"></script>
```

in head section :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9;IE=edge;IE=10" />
```

Comment: This helps, but it's still trying to fetch the files from the /p directory.